# Analyze Shakespeare's Macbeth parsing XML from web using Nokogiri

Tags: beginner, ruby, parsing, unit-testing, xml

This is a simple Ruby program to analyze the number of lines characters speak in Shakespeare's *Macbeth* using Nokogiri and open-uri to parse a given url containing xml. I wrote this as practice getting used to Ruby and TDD.

I'm new to Ruby so I'm wondering if anything looks strange to more experienced Rubyists.

Note: I had trouble comparing hashes in the spec `"correctly analyzes character line counts"`. Even after calling `to_s` on both, it looks equal but the test fails. I had trouble with that. I'm wondering if this is even a good test to make with large hashes?

**Also**: I was wondering if I should be testing the calls using open-uri `open`? I didn't want to download from the webpage in the tests. I'd appreciate it if someone might demonstrate how to do this. I tried using a Mock with something like `expect(Kernel).to receive(:open).with(MACBETH_URL)` but had trouble with it.

Given:

> Write a command-line program that prints the number of lines spoken by each character in the play.
>
> Sample usage/output (using made-up numbers):
>
> ```
> $ ruby macbeth_analyzer.rb
>   543 Macbeth
>   345 Banquo
>   220 Duncan
>  (etc.)
> ```
>
> You can find an XML-encoded version of Macbeth here: http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/macbeth.xml. Your program should download and parse this file at runtime.
>
> Your solution must be tested, preferably via TDD. Running your tests should not download the play from the ibiblio.org server.
>
> Note: some lines are attributed to a speaker called "ALL". Your program should ignore these.

**macbeth_analyzer.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative 'parser'
require_relative 'printer'

class MacbethAnalyzer
  attr_reader :speaker_line_counts

  MACBETH_URL = "http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/macbeth.xml"
  IGNORE_SPEAKERS = %w(ALL)

  def initialize
    @parser = Parser.new(MACBETH_URL)
    @speaker_line_counts = analyze_speaker_line_counts
  end

  def analyze_speaker_line_counts
    speaker_line_counts = Hash.new(0)
    speakers = @parser.parse(query: '//SPEAKER')
    speakers.map do |speaker|
      unless IGNORE_SPEAKERS.include? speaker.text
        speaker_line_counts[speaker.text] += @parser.parse(
          node: speaker, query: '../LINE').count
      end
    end
    speaker_line_counts
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  analyzer = MacbethAnalyzer.new
  Printer.print_hash_val_capitalized_key(
    hash: analyzer.speaker_line_counts, filter: 'ALL')
end
```

**macbeth_analyzer_spec.rb**

```
require 'macbeth_analyzer'

describe MacbethAnalyzer do
  describe "#analyze_speaker_line_counts" do
    it "analyzes speaker line counts and stores in hash" do
      SPEAKER_HASH_COUNT = 40
      analyzer = MacbethAnalyzer.new

      result = analyzer.analyze_speaker_line_counts

      expect(result.count).to eq(SPEAKER_HASH_COUNT)
      expect(result["MACBETH"]).to eq(719)
      expect(result["BANQUO"]).to eq(113)
      expect(result["DUNCAN"]).to eq(70)
    end

    it "should ignore speaker title 'ALL'" do
      analyzer = MacbethAnalyzer.new

      result = analyzer.analyze_speaker_line_counts

      expect(result["ALL"]).to eq(0)
    end

    xit "correctly analyzes character line counts" do
      macbeth_line_counts = {
        "First Witch":       62,
        "Second Witch":      27,
        "Third Witch":       27,
        "DUNCAN":            70,
        "MALCOLM":           212,
        "Sergeant":          35,
        "LENNOX":            74,
        "ROSS":              135,
        "MACBETH":           719,
        "BANQUO":            113,
        "ANGUS":             21,
        "LADY MACBETH":      265,
        "Messenger":         23,
        "FLEANCE":           2,
        "Porter":            46,
        "MACDUFF":           180,
        "DONALBAIN":         10,
        "Old Man":           11,
        "ATTENDANT":         1,
        "First Murderer":    30,
        "Second Murderer":   15,
        "Both Murderers":    2,
        "Servant":           5,
        "Third Murderer":    8,
        "Lords":             3,
        "HECATE":            39,
        "Lord":              21,
        "First Apparition":  2,
        "Second Apparition": 4,
        "Third Apparition":  5,
        "LADY MACDUFF":      41,
        "Son":               20,
        "Doctor":            45,
        "Gentlewoman":       23,
        "MENTEITH":          12,
        "CAITHNESS":         11,
        "SEYTON":            5,
        "SIWARD":            30,
        "Soldiers":          1,
        "YOUNG SIWARD":      7
      }

      macbeth = MacbethAnalyzer.new
      result = macbeth.analyze_speaker_line_counts

      # TODO: how to make this pass? tried to_s both
      expect(result).to eq(macbeth_line_counts)
    end
  end
end
```

**parser.rb**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class Parser
  def initialize(url)
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
  end

  def parse(node: @doc, query:)
    node.xpath(query)
  end
end
```

**parser_spec.rb**

```
require 'parser'

describe Parser do
  describe "#parse" do
    it "parses speaker nodes" do
      SPEAKER_COUNT = 650
      parser = Parser.new('spec/fixtures/macbeth.xml')

      result = parser.parse(query: '//SPEAKER')

      expect(result.count).to eq(SPEAKER_COUNT)
    end
  end
end
```

**printer.rb**

```
class Printer
  def self.print_hash_val_capitalized_key(hash:, filter: nil)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      puts "#{value} #{key.capitalize}" unless key.to_s === filter
    end
  end
end
```

**printer_spec.rb**

```
require 'printer'

describe Printer do
  describe "#print_hash_val_capitalized_key" do
    it "prints a hash of name keys capitalized and count values" do
      test_hash = {
        "LENNOX":  74,
        "ROSS":    135,
        "MACBETH": 719,
      }

      expect{Printer.print_hash_val_capitalized_key(hash: test_hash)}.to output(
        "74 Lennox\n135 Ross\n719 Macbeth\n").to_stdout
    end

    it "excludes a given filter from output" do
      test_hash = {
        "LENNOX":  74,
        "ALL":     24,
        "ROSS":    135,
        "MACBETH": 719,
      }

      expect{Printer.print_hash_val_capitalized_key(hash: test_hash, filter: "ALL")}.to output(
        "74 Lennox\n135 Ross\n719 Macbeth\n").to_stdout
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Naming

#### *Choose Names at the Appropriate Level of Abstraction*

I noticed an issue that reminded me of something I read in *Clean Code*, which says:

> "Don’t pick names that communicate implementation; choose names the reflect the level of abstraction of the class or function you are working in." (Martin, 311)

Martin gives an example of a Modem interface that contains:

```
boolean dial(String phoneNumber);
```

He points out that in some applications, modems aren't connected by dailing but rather hardwiring or sending a port number, etc. The point is that using `phoneNumber` is the wrong level of abstraction. He suggests changing to:

```
boolean connect(String connectionLocator);
```

This better communicates the ways a consumer could use the interface.

The relation to my application is in Parser:

```
class Parser
  def initialize(url)
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
  end
  ...
```

`open-uri`'s `open()` takes a **uri** (who would've thought?). A **uri** is a level of abstraction above a **url**. In the tests, I initialize a `Parser` object with a local xml fixture uri (not a url):

```
parser = Parser.new('spec/fixtures/macbeth.xml')
```

Therefore, Parser should become:

```
class Parser
  def initialize(uri)
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(uri))
  end
  ...
```

So this may seem rather trivial in the context of my small application but it does reflect a valuable lesson from *Clean Code* in choosing names at the appropriate level of abstraction.

#### *Make Meaningful Distinctions*

When I started working on this problem, early on I decided what the responsibilities would be. I reasoned that we'd need a concrete runner class *MacbethAnalyzer* that's responsible for handling the specifics of the problem statement, a *Parser*, who's responsible for parsing, and a *Printer* to handle print.

Having completed a working implementation, I notice that `Parser` is only responsible for parsing Xml, which has a clear dependency in the constructor:

```
class Parser
  def initialize(uri)
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(uri))
  end
```

The given problem is small, but it's easy to imagine a larger project where we parse from several sources of varying formats beyond XML. It seems clear that class `Parser` isn't specific enough and should be more meaningfully distinguished by renaming to `XmlParser`.

---

## Dependency Inversion Principle

The constructor of `MacbethAnalzyer` has tight coupling in the dependency to the low-level implementation details of `XmlParser`:

```
class MacbethAnalyzer
    @parser = XmlParser.new(MACBETH_URL)
    @speaker_line_counts = analyze_speaker_line_counts
  end
```

What if `XmlParser` changes? What if we wanted to use a different kind of Parser? What if we wanted to construct a Fake object for testing and pass that to `MacbethAnalyzer`? These are issues related to the Dependency Inversion Principle.

The solution here is to use "dependency injection" to inject `Parser` into `MacbethAnalyzer`:

```
class MacbethAnalyzer
  attr_reader :speaker_line_counts

  MACBETH_URL = "http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/macbeth.xml"
  IGNORE_SPEAKERS = %w(ALL)

  def initialize(parser)
    @parser = parser
    @speaker_line_counts = analyze_speaker_line_counts
  end

  def analyze_speaker_line_counts
    speaker_line_counts = Hash.new(0)
    speakers = parser.parse(query: '//SPEAKER')
    speakers.map do |speaker|
      unless IGNORE_SPEAKERS.include? speaker.text
        speaker_line_counts[speaker.text] += parser.parse(
          node: speaker, query: '../LINE').count
      end
    end
    speaker_line_counts
  end

  private

  attr_reader :parser
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  analyzer = MacbethAnalyzer.new(XmlParser.new(MACBETH_URL))
  Printer.print_hash_val_capitalized_key(
    hash: analyzer.speaker_line_counts, filter: 'ALL')
end
```

Now `MacbethAnalyzer` doesn't depend on a lower-level implementation; we use duck typing to make things flexible, removing the dependency and resulting in much more loosely coupled code.